# AVCaptureDeviceInput Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, null

I'm trying to get the image of the capturing device but it keeps returning nil by `if let input...` and I can't find a solution.

It tries to catch the error but it instantly cashes..

```
let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

    do {
        if let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera!) as? AVCaptureInput {
            if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))! {
                captureSession?.addInput(input)

                stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
                let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
                let settingsFormat = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]
                settings.previewPhotoFormat = settingsFormat

                stillImageOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self as! AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)

                if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput!))! {
                    captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)

                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
                    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
                    previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

                    captureSession?.startRunning()
                }
            }
        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying this on the device or simulator? Simulator may return nil for the cameras. Also try this for the back camera `let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your error throwing that's causing the crash - it's all your force unwrapping.  `backCamera`, `captureSession`, `stillImageOutput`, and `previewLayer` are all `Optional`s, but you're force unwrapping all of them every time.  Why not use guard statements or optional binding to avoid those crashes?  Ultimately you can't run any of that code if those items are nil, so I'd refactor your code like this:

```
//Use guard to make sure you have a non-nil captureSession and a default device for .video
guard let captureSession = captureSession, let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else { return }

do {
    if let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) as? AVCaptureInput {
        if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

            //Since stillImageOutput is an Optional I'm putting in another guard just to avoid having to deal with it as an Optional
            guard let stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput else { return }

            let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            let settingsFormat = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]
            settings.previewPhotoFormat = settingsFormat

            stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self as! AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)

            if (captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput)) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

                //Same as above - since you declared previewLayer as Optional I'll guard so I don't have to deal with it as an Optional
                guard let previewLayer = previewLayer else { return }

                previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
                previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
} catch let error {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Honestly some of this is a bit overkill, so it's down to a bit of personal preference, but with something like `AVCaptureDevice.default...` where it truly may or may not be nil depending on the actual device you probably *don't* want to let it crash if it doesn't exist.